# Adding element with text breaking responsiveness of website

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

When adding an element (in this case I am trying to add a `<p>` tag but it's the same result on any element) to add text below my images on a custom carousel, the responsive design on my site breaks. It only appears to break when the text reaches a length of 2 or greater. If the text is very short (1 character) the responsive design still works. See images below:

**No text element here just the image @viewport of 375px:**

[image: No text element, just the image @viewport of 375px]

**Here added the `<p>` @viewport of 375px:**

[image]

As you can see from the images, the text above the carousel no longer collapses once the text is added to the carousel divs. But if you hard code the values to a single character it works again.

**Note:** I'm using framer motion to animate the carousel.

**Carousel.tsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { data } from "../data";

import "../styles/Carousel/Carousel.css";
import { reverse } from "dns";

function AutoCarousel() {
  const translateArr = createTranslateArray(85);
  console.log(translateArr);

  const carouselItems = data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <motion.div
        animate={{ transform: translateArr }}
        transition={{
          duration: 10,
          repeat: Infinity,
          repeatType: "reverse",
          ease: "linear",
          delay: 0,
        }}
        className={`item ${index}`}
        key={index}
      >
        <img src={item.src} />
        <p>{item.title}</p> {/* Adding this breaks responsive design */}
      </motion.div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="carousel-container">
      <div className="carousel">
        {carouselItems}
        {carouselItems}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Carousel.css:**

```
.carousel-container {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item > p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
}

.item > img {
  width: 50%;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .carousel-container {
    height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .item {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
  }
}
```

**repo:** https://github.com/Kyle-Close/portfolio

I have tried making the container div a flexbox and set the overflow to hidden with no luck.

I tried tinkering with the values and it seems to just come down to how much space the text occupies, As soon as the text occupies a small amount of space the responsive design breaks.

I can visually see however, that there is plenty of space for the text to fit in the flexbox with the image.

What I expect is to fit text below each image in the carousel and have all the text/elements above the carousel still collapse as they would when the text is not in the carousel.